# How to fix a Full Screen Terminal that believes it is 9 lines bigger than it is

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, xfce4-terminal

My terminal works normally but when I hit the bottom of the screen it doesn't start scrolling upwards until I'm about 9 lines off screen.  So I can see what I typed if I hit enter 9 times.

This only happens if the terminal is full screen, if I make it smaller then it will scroll normally when I hit bottom.

Where is this set?

Edit: I'm using XFCE Terminal.  Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: what "Full Screen Terminal" is that, and why do you think that full details and a clear description don't matter?

Comment: @mosvy Point.  Apologies for the lack of clarity.  Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, can you see all the edges of the terminal window when in full screen mode? If the bottom edge is not visible, it might be that your display is mis-adjusted so that the bottom part of the image goes beyond the screen. That can usually be fixed using the controls in the actual physical display.

If that's not the problem, then make sure the `xterm` package is installed (install it if necessary) and then run

```
eval $(resize)
```

in the terminal window that is suffering from the problem.

If you're using `su` or `sudo` to transition from one user to another within a terminal session, that will interrupt the passing of the "terminal has been resized" signal (`SIGWINCH`) from the terminal emulator (running as the original user) to the shell/application in question (running as a different user). The command above will force the re-evaluation of terminal screen size, as a substitute for the missing signal.

If this does not help, try changing the font in the terminal you're using: if the font you're using misreports its character height slightly, it might accumulate an error of about 9 lines when using full screen mode, but depending on the resolution of your screen, the error might be unnoticeable when using a smaller terminal window (e.g. the classic 80x24 default size). If changing the font helps, consider making a bug report for the font package containing the original font.

Comment: You are a God!  I had to install xterm, which also made me "apt --fix-broken install" to fix some broken dependencies which might have also been part of the issue before I could "eval $(resize)".  Thank you!